# Detect character by comparing images of different dimensions

Tags: matlab, image-processing, ocr, dimensions

I seem to have stumbled upon a small problem while developing an Optical Character Recognition engine. I have trained the K nearest neighbour classifier on MNIST images and even tested it. It seems to work fine. However, when I input images of different dimensions, it seems unable to classify the input image correctly.
Any suggestions on how to work around this problem ?

**I] KNN Classifier -**

the code for knn classification is :

```
 % herein, I resize the binary image 'b' to contain the 
 % same dimensions as the training set 'trainingImages' as the input and training Images    
 % should have the same no. of columns / dimensions

b = imresize(b, size(trainingImages));

 % now i try to classify the input image 'b' against the set of training images and   
 % training labels.

cls = knnclassify(b, trainingImages, trainingLabels, 3, 'euclidean');
```

cls is now the classification vector. However, this almost always shows the incorrect classification of 1 regardless of the input image.

On the other hand, when I classify the set of MNIST test images, I get a VERY high level of accuracy! The code for the same is as follows -

```
class = knnclassify(testImg, trainingImages, trainingLabels, 3, 'euclidean');
```

Right now the main problem is, no matter what kind of input image I give it to predict, it mostly gives me a wrong result (varying for different images), even for those very different images. Seems like it is not working correctly. Could someone help me check out where should be the problem here? I couldn't find any explanation from the existing sources on the internet. Thanks in advance.

Comment: if the training set trainingImages contains all the template images, then you are resizing the single image b to your training set size. you should set b's size to the size of a single character in your training set

Comment: Thanks Dhanushka!
I too arrived at that conclusion late last eve.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I solved the problem which I listed above.
The problems were :

1. Like Dhanushka said, I was converting the original input image's dimensions to match that of the training image set's dimensions (which in the case of MNIST was 60000 * 784, implying 60000 digits and 784 features for each digit [28 * 28] ).
   Thus, I simply changed the dimension of the input image to 28*28.
2. Pre-processing the input image.
    I was simply converting the image to the binary image and trying to classify that against the MNIST training image data set. This was an *INCOMPLETE* procedure.
    When I further detected the edges of the input binary image (Canny, Prewitt or Zerocross - whichever suits you better) and used this for classification, I got an extremely accurate prediction!

NOTE : In KNN classification, you will have to arrive at the number of neighbouring pixels to consider by trial and error. I managed to arrive at the following conclusions -

1. 3 neighbouring pixels are generally enough for synthetic images
2. 1 neighbouring pixel is mostly suitable for handwritten images

The code for the same is as follows :

```
    % herein, I resize the binary image 'b' as the input and training Images    
    % should have the same no. of columns / dimensions

    b = imresize(b, [28 28]);    % this resizes the binary image b to 28*28 dimension
    b = edge(b, 'canny');        % this uses Canny edge detection on the resized binary 
                                 % image
    b = b(:)';                   % This converts 'b' to a vector using b(:) and then
                                 % transposes the result using the " ' " operator
                                 % Thus, now 'b' has same no of dimensions/columns as 
                                 % MNIST training image set

    % now i try to classify the input image 'b' against the set of training images  
    % and training labels.

    cls = knnclassify(b, trainingImages, trainingLabels, 3, 'euclidean');
```